# How to extract data from Nutch crawled data?

Tags: hbase, nutch

Apache Nutch crawled some data that was saved in `hbase`. Those data contains some pdfs files. Now I want to extract those files.

How I can do that it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hbase don't understand what type of data is stored. I think you can use *readdb* command (http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20readdb ) in  HBase shell to extract data from webpage table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nutch dump command

Here is the syntax:

```
bin/nutch dump -outputDir <path_of_output_dir> -segment <segments_dir>
```

Example:

```
bin/nutch dump -outputDir /tmp/tt03 -segment crawl/crawldb/segments
```

Answer (score 0):

As you certainly know, crawled data are stored in segments. You can actually extract those data using **readseg** command (for example):

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump /work/apache-nutch-1.12/crawl/segments/20161005134205 my_dump_dir
```

where **my_dump_dir** is your directory, which will be created and contain dump.

Then in your my_dump_dir you'll find two files: **dump** (contains crawled and parsed data - non_encoded), and  **.dump.crc** (i guess some binary). They view **dump** with any text editor and view the structure. You can also parse it, if you need.